# How to set inputType for Android Direct Reply

Tags: android

I'm implementing Direct Reply for my Android App. In my App, I want users only input numbers in the notification Direct Reply. By Default, the keyboard for this reply is text. So it's not easy for users to input numbers.

How can I specify the keyboard for direct reply? Like what we do for EditText

```
            android:inputType="phone"
```

I just copy the code from the official tutorial,  https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#direct

```
// Key for the string that's delivered in the action's intent.
private static final String KEY_TEXT_REPLY = "key_text_reply";
String replyLabel = getResources().getString(R.string.reply_label);
RemoteInput remoteInput = new RemoteInput.Builder(KEY_TEXT_REPLY)
    .setLabel(replyLabel)
    .build();
```

[image]

Comment: Can you post a code for this RemoteInput?

Comment: @GreenRobo Thanks for your reply. I updated the code in the question. I don't know if there is a build-in method to implement it. I checked the document for RemoteInput, but didn't find my answer https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/RemoteInput.html